# Cannot display buttons correctly in pycord

Tags: python, button, pycord

I have a view class:

```py
class genagain(discord.ui.View):

    @discord.ui.button(label="U1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="u1", row=0)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="U2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="u2", row=0)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="U3", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="u3", row=0)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="U4", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="u4", row=0)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="", custom_id="genagain", row=1)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="V1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="v1", row=2)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="V2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="v2", row=2)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="V3", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="v3", row=2)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="V4", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="v4", row=2)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.response("Generating again...")
```

What the code should do is to create 9 buttons of 3 rows and respond "Generating again..." if the button is pressed.

But this is the result: [image: The result]

Why there is only the last button displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each button needs it's own [unique callback function](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/ui-components/buttons). Did you try renaming the various functions?